# I wanna figure out the numbers in an arithmetic sequence question

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

> 12. The sum of  three   consecutive terms   in  an  arithmetic  sequence    is  21  and the product of  the two extreme numbers is  45. Find the numbers.

How would we go on about finding this?!

Answer (score 1):

We have two equations. From the first sentence, we have $(x - d) + x + (x + d) = 21$, where $d$ is the common difference of the arithmetic sequence. We can solve this equation to find $x$, though $d$ is still unknown. Then from the second sequence, we have $(x - d)(x + d) = 45$; with the known value of $x$, we can solve for $d$, then use $x$ and $d$ to find the original three numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a series $\dots ,a-x,a,a+x,\dots$. Then 
$$21 = (a-x) + a + (a+x) = 3a.$$
Hence, $a = 7$. As we also have 
$$45 = (a-x)(a+x) = (7-x)(7+x) = 49 - x^2$$. 
Hence, $x^2 = 4$. So we get $x = 2\vee x = -2$.

So the numbers are $(7,2)$ and $(7,-2)$.

Note that one gives us an increasing sequence, while the other gives a decreasing sequence.

Comment: The question is asking for the three numbers $a - x, a, a + x$; both $x = 2$ and $x = -2$ give the same solution.